Jetpack Compose view not drawing when coming back to fragment from Fragment to Jetpack Compose Screen
I've used composed view(for display button) in my already exiting xml. Issue is my I back to this fragment from anther Fragment compose  view button not visible rest all xml view are visible.
How i can resolved this issue ?
with(binding.watchContainer.watchComposeView) {
                this?.setViewCompositionStrategy(ViewCompositionStrategy.DisposeOnLifecycleDestroyed)
                this?.setContent {

                    WatchButton(
                        buttonText =  "Login Btn",
                        isLoading = false,
                        isTablet = false,
                        onClick = { requestSignIn() }
                    )
                }
            }   


did you get the solution? I am also facing the same problem, I tried somethings but did not work :/
